# Performances increase for ffmpeg on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ffmpeg

### Situation

I am using `ffmpeg` to create GIFs from MKV files, adding subtitles from SRT files. My command usually looks like this:

```bash
ffmpeg -y -ss <start_time> -to <end_time> -copyts -i <MKV file> -ss <start_time> -to <end_time> 
  -vf "scale=512:-1,split[pal][sub];[pal]palettegen[p];[sub][p]paletteuse,subtitles=<SRT file>:force_style='Fontname=<FontName>,Fontsize=35':fontsdir=<Fonts dir>"
  "<output file>.gif"
```

I need this to run on a RPi3.

### Objective

This is currently working, but is rather slow (anywhere from 15 to 30 seconds for reasonably long GIFs, can be more for lengthy ones). I want it to be the fastest possible, while quality must be reasonable, think good enough to use in chats with friends, and size must be reasonable, again think usable in chats with friends.

### Method tried

In accordance to the [FFmpeg documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset), I tried using presets, and in particular, the `ultrafast` one. This leads to a command such as:

```bash
ffmpeg -y -ss <start_time> -to <end_time> -copyts -i <MKV file> -ss <start_time> -to <end_time> -preset ultrafast 
  -vf "scale=512:-1,split[pal][sub];[pal]palettegen[p];[sub][p]paletteuse,subtitles=<SRT file>:force_style='Fontname=<FontName>,Fontsize=35':fontsdir=<Fonts dir>"
  "<output file>.gif"
```

### Expected result

I tried this command on my computer, and the results were really impressive, the GIFs being generated almost instantaneously. Extrapolating from this result, I assumed that the time to generate a GIF from my RPi would noticeably decrease.

### Result

In practice, the generation time did not change (or the change was sub 1 second, the logs only displaying the seconds).

### Why, how?

Why is it doing nothing? I can't seem to find if the `ffmpeg` process already choose a preset adapted to the physical machine it runs on (and here, it would have chosen the ultrafast preset by default, the RPi not being powerful enough), or if something in the RPi architecture is incompatible with such presets. This could also be caused by a mistake on my part in the command (though obtaining the expected result on my computer makes me think it would not be this).

This said, how can I still improve the generation time? Is there anything (option, pre-processing, ...) that can be done to reduce it? Again, the quality reduction/size augmentation may only be sustainable to a certain extent.

Thanks to all of you reading!

Comment: you're creating a GIF ... `-preset` that you linked to is for H.264 encoder, which is completely irrelevant when creating a GIF - I doubt the `-preset` made any difference at all on  your "computer"

Comment: I will check again, but I'm quite positive the generation times were really different. I interpreted it as being caused by the `-preset` argument, but it might not be the case. I would love to understand why it produces such differences then... Additionally, now that it is said that the `-preset` don't make any difference, is there any way to improve the GIF generation speed?